# Preposition with dativ

Tags: preposition, dative, standard-german

> Ich habe um 8:00 Uhr ein Meeting mit Kollegen aus der Marketing-Abteilung. Um 11:00 Uhr muss ich dann _____ einem Kollegen sein.

Please tell me why/how the answer of the gap is *"bei"* and not *"mit"* or *"zu"*. Most importantly: why *"bei"? The grammar behind it.

I have researched all over and found 12 conditions to use *"bei"* but none of them seems right:

> - when someone's at your place,
> - when you have something on you + reflexive pronoun,
> - when you are with a professional at his/her place,
> - when describing working at a place,
> - ordering something on company's website,
> - when you are near a place or by a place,
> - in a sense of during,
> - with nominalized nouns,
> - temperature and numbers,
> - with verbs that uses bei,
> - in case of or in certain condition,
> - when you are talking about someone else's situation or your own situation

Comment: Could you please add (in short) those 12 conditions and why you think, they aren't correct? This might help to identify, whether your sources are not correct or where you might have gotten something wrong.

Comment: Just curious: why the very first condition didn't seem right to you?

Comment: Because the sentence had sein at the end. That's way I was confused.

Comment: @saaras maybe you mixed up _sein_ (to be) with _sein_ (his) in this sentence? That could explain the confusion :)

Answer (score 3):

It's the "sein" at the end of the sentence that enforces the "bei".

You could write *"Um 11:00 muss ich dann **zu** einem Kollegen **gehen**."*
or *"Um 11:00 muss ich dann **mit** einem Kollegen **arbeiten**."*

"bei jemandem sein" means to be at someone's place. *"Ich werde bei meinem Freund sein"* means that I will be at my friend's place (not just be *with* him).

So the sentence answers the question: "Where do you have to be at 11:00?" - "I'll have to be *at* my collegue's place."

Answer (score 3):

According to my grammar book, *bei* is used with reference to people, usually means 'at (the house of)'. It is also used to indicate place of employment. Examples:

- Sie wohnt bei ihrer Tante.
- Bei uns.
- Bei uns in der Fabrik.

So, in your text, 'bei' seems an acceptable answer to me, and it indicates the idea of being in that collegue's 'office'.

Comment: Yeah, it is clear now I was confused because of the sein at the end.

Answer (score 1):

### bei

- local
  something is located *near by* or *next to* something else

  > Baden liegt *bei* Wien
  >   Baden is *next to* Vienna
- temporal
  at a certain time

  > Haben Sie Wien schon *bei* Nacht gesehen?
  >   Did you see Vienna *at* night?
- modal
  used to express certain circumstances

  > *Bei* deinem Einkommen kannst du dir das ja locker leisten.
  >   *With* your income, you can easily afford that.

---

### mit

- modal only
  You use *"mit"* if one thing or person is compound with another

  > Ich gehe *mit* meiner Frau ins Kino.
  >   I go to the movies *with* my wife.
  >
  > Ich habe ein Spielzeugauto *mit* Fernbedienung.
  >   I have a toy car *with* remote control.

  Or if you use a device

  > Ich fahre *mit* dem Zug.
  >   I take the train.
  >
  > Hans schlägt den Nagel *mit* einem Hammer in the Wand.
  >   Hans hits the nail *with* a Hammer into the wall.

---

### zu

- local
  Heading in a direction

  > Ich gehe *zu* meinem Chef.
  >   I go *to* my boss.
- temporal
  at a certain time

  > *Zu* Ostern hat es geregnet.
  >   It rained *at* Easter.
- modal
  in relation to something

  > Diese Mischung besteht *zu* einem Drittel aus Sand.
  >   One third of this mixture is sand.

---

### So, what does that mean for your question?

> Um 11:00 Uhr muss ich dann _____ einem Kollegen sein.

At 11 o'clock you have to be where your college is, i.e you have to be next to him or her. So we are talking about a place where you have to be.

*"Mit"* can't be used in local mode, so it never can mean a location.

*"Zu"* can be used local, but then it only can express a direction. But we need something that expresses a place, so it canÄt be *zu*.

*"Bei"* is perfect. It expresses a place near by someone else. So, it has to be:

> Um 11:00 Uhr muss ich dann **bei** einem Kollegen sein.